# How to tokenize input for variable amount of words

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, tokenize

In here I am trying to tokenize the user input e.g. `load sml.txt`.
The load command works fine because it has 2 tokens, but if I try to use a single word input like `display`, it crashes and gives me a segfault. I assume its because the second token is NULL, but I have no idea how to circumvent this issue.  Can you help?

For your reference COMMAND_LOAD = "load" and COMMAND_DISPLAY = "display".

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    AddressBookList *addressBookList;
    char input[BUFSIZ];
    char load[BUFSIZ];
    char fileN[BUFSIZ];
    char *fileName;
    char *token;
    showStudentInformation();
    do
    {
        printf("Enter your command: \n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
        token = strtok(input, " ");
        strcpy(load, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy(fileN, token);
        fileName = fileN;
        if (strcmp(load, COMMAND_LOAD) == 0)
        {
            addressBookList = commandLoad(fileName);
        }
        else if (strcmp(load, COMMAND_UNLOAD) == 0)
        {
            /*commandUnload(fileName);*/
        }
        else if (strcmp(load, COMMAND_DISPLAY) == 0)
        {
            if (fileN == NULL)
            {
                printf("> No file loaded");
            }
            else
            {
                commandDisplay(addressBookList);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("> Invalid input\n\n");
        }
    } while (strcmp(load, COMMAND_QUIT) != 0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Check whether `token` is `NULL` before calling `strcpy()`.

Comment: You need to check the return of `strtok`to see if it is NULL before trying to do anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok()` returns `NULL` when there's no more tokens, you can check for this. If there's no token, I empty the target string by assigning `'\0'` to the first character, instead of calling `strcpy()`.

```
do
{
    printf("Enter your command: \n");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    token = strtok(input, " \n");
    if (token) {
        strcpy(load, token);
    } else {
        load[0] = '\0';
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    if (token) {
        strcpy(fileN, token);
    } else {
        fileN[0] = '\0';
    }
    ...
} while (strcmp(load, COMMAND_QUIT) != 0);
```

There's also no need to replace the last character in the string with `\0`. Just include `\n` in the `strtok()` delimiters, so it won't include the newline at the end in the token.

Comment: Thanks for this response, but how the tokens are saved even outside the if statements? It does work but I'm just trying to understand as I'm new to C

Comment: If the token is found, it uses `strcpy()` to copy it to the variable. If there's no token, it just sets the variable to an empty string with `variable[0] = '\0';`